# How to dynamically set defaultValue in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a page to edit `Product`, `props` value are taken from an API and it's coming from parent component. How do I set this value to my `Datepicker` input? Because `defaultValue` from `react-hook-form` is cached at the first render within the custom hook, so I'm getting `null`.

```
const ProductEdit = (props) => {
  const { product } = props;
  const { control, register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  ........

  <Controller
     control={control}
     name='dateLaunch'
     defaultValue={() => {
        console.log(product); // return null
     }}
     render={({ field }) => (
        <DatePicker
           selected={field.value}
           onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
        />
     )}
  />
}
```

defaultValues is cached at the first render within the custom hook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `reset` here and call it when `product` changed via `useEffect`. I assume, that `product` has a property named `dateLaunch`.

```
const ProductEdit = (props) => {
    const { product } = props;
    const { control, register, handleSubmit, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

    useEffect(() => {
        reset(product)
    }, [product]);
  
    // ...
    
    <Controller
        control={control}
        name='dateLaunch'
        defaultValue={null}
        render={({ field }) => (
            <DatePicker
                selected={field.value}
                onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)} />
        )} />
};
```

Comment: this works for me, thanks! One question, what is the bracket `[product]` at the end of `useEffect` means?

Comment: This is called the dependency array from `useEffect`. With this you can control when your effect should run - in your case it will run every time when the `product` prop changes. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) you can find more information about `useEffect` and all the possible use cases for the dependency array.

Comment: Why we are not using setValue here ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use register

```
    const ProductEdit = (props) => {
      const { product } = props;
      const { control, register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
           defaultValues: {
              inputOneName: props.name,
              inputTwoName: props.lastname
           }

});
```

Comment: I've tried `useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      dateLaunch: props.product.dateLaunch
    }
  })` and it is not working as the value is null, error `Cannot read property 'dateLaunch' of null`